# Convert microtime(true) to javascript date object

Tags: javascript, php, date, time, microtime

Can the value of PHP's `microtime(true)` be converted to a javascript date object, and the accuracy to be preserved ?

Comment: ECMAScript Dates use a time value that is milliseconds, so you can't preserve microsecond precision unless you keep track of it yourself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can easily use the output of `microtime` to create a JavaScript Date object, like this:

```
new Date(<?php echo microtime(true) * 1000 ?>)
```

Couple things to note here though.

1. `microtime(true)` returns time in seconds, accurate to microseconds. You have to multiple this by 1000 to have a millisecond value for your `Date` object.
2. You are only then preserving millisecond precision, not the entire microsecond precision. JavaScript's `Date` does not support sub-millisecond precision.

(Also, I assume you'll pass the microtime value from the server some other way, hopefully you're not *actually* spitting out PHP in the middle of your JavaScript code.)

Comment: @RobG Right, the _output_ of `microtime(true)` needs to be multiplied by 1000 to get milliseconds. My original answer was not very clear on that, I updated. Thanks!

Comment: Ok. The original seconds value might be "accurate to microseconds" but a value can't be more accurate than its highest precision, which is seconds. It can't gain accuracy just by adding zeros (despite [*php.net*](http://php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php) saying it's "accurate to the nearest microsecond"). ;-)